# How to fetch MongoDB documents with Mongoose from the beginning of the year till current date

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I would like to fetch MongoDB documents using mongoose. And I want to fetch in such a way that documents fetched are documents created from the beginning of the year till present date. All suggestions will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have timestamp or creation date in your schema? If yes just make a filter for that based on your requirements.

Comment: Yes I have `createdAt` in the schema which defaults to `Date.now`. I'll try that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basing the following from your follow-up comments on the question, with a date field `createdAt` you can construct a date range query (using the **[`Date()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)** constructor to create date instances) and obtain the desired result as follows:

```
var start = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), 0, 1), // get first day of current year
    end = new Date(); // current date 

Model.find({ "createdAt": { "$gte": start, "$lte": end }})
    .exec(callback);
```

Using momentjs library, getting the beginning of the current year date can be achieved by the **[`startOf()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/)** method:

```
var start =  moment().startOf('year'), // set to January 1st, 12:00 am this year
    end = moment(); // current date
```